# Word boundary before special character fails the match

Tags: c#, regex

Here's what I've tried

```
CSharpClassNameRegex = new Regex(@"\b(\x36|class|\$|function|struct|enum|interface)(?<range>\w+?)\b", RegexCompiledOption);
```

where \x36 and \$ represent '$'

These are not returning a match, although the other keywords are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` symbol is not  a word char, and `\b` requires a word char before it.

You may fix your regex using an unambiguous left word boundary, `(?<!\w)`:

```
CSharpClassNameRegex = new Regex(@"(?<!\w)(class|\$|function|struct|enum|interface)(?<range>\w+)", RegexCompiledOption);
```

Note that `\w+?\b` can be replaced with `\w+` safely, `\w+` will greedily match 1 or more word chars and you do not have to enforce matching 1 or more word chars with a word boundary.

Also, `\x36`  matches `6` char, so I doubt you need to keep it in the regex.

**Regex details**

- `(?<!\w)` - no word char is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(class|\$|function|struct|enum|interface)` - Group 1: `class`, `$`, `function`, `struct`, `enum`, `interface` substrings
- `(?<range>\w+)` - Named group "range": 1 or more word chars.

Comment: This is what I needed!