# Match phone numbers with area codes using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, match

**Question:** 
How can I capture all versions of Region code combinations + PhoneNumber using regex?
Requirements are as follows:
Area code matching "", "+45 or "0045" followed up by 8 digits with no non whitespace/newline characters on either side of the whole match.

**Context** 
I am trying to make a regex to match a Danish phone number. These numbers are 8 digits, or 4 groups of 2 digits(I will leave the second example out for sake of simplicity) spanning from 20 00 00 00 to 99 99 99 99 with a country code prefix that can either be nothing, +45 or 0045. 
Some examples of these could be:

- *20242024*
- *+4550505151*
- *004541424344*

**Problem** 
I am unable to capture +45 phone numbers while the two other examples are captured with no problem and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

**My code** 
My regex String is as follows: `\b(?<Region>\+45|0045|)(?<PhoneNumber>([2-9][0-9])([0-9]{2}){3}\b)` 
Build using this: https://regexr.com/4uqfu

My currently working code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(?<Region>\+45|0045|)(?<PhoneNumber>([2-9][0-9])([0-9]{2}){3}\b)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string input = "20212223 004520212223 +4520212223 24546577 12467223";

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
Console.WriteLine("Found " + matches.Count + " Matches");
int i = 1;
foreach(Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " + match);
    Console.WriteLine("  Region: " + match.Groups["Region"]);
    Console.WriteLine("  Phone Number: " + match.Groups["PhoneNumber"]);
    i++;
}
```

Console output log:

```
Found 3 Matches
1 20212223
  Region: 
  Phone Number: 20212223
2 004520212223
  Region: 0045
  Phone Number: 20212223
3 24546577
  Region: 
  Phone Number: 24546577
```

> Please note: 
>   All phone numbers referenced here are nothing more than random button mashing and I do not have any idea if they are owned or who owns these numbers. Please do not try to contact any of them.
>   I am a rookie at regex and are still learning so bear over with me if it's a simple fix.

Comment: You require a word char to be before `+45` (`+` is not a word char) with `\b`. Replace the first `\b` with `(?<!\w)`

Comment: hmm interesting, it seems to do the trick, I really don't know why or how it works tho. I am very interested in learning so could I ask of you to add in an answer explaining why and what does what?

Comment: I have answered how to fix the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210191/3832970). Let me know what is not clear, I will add.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I tried searching around and didn't find this solution. I apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to point out that there still is some unwanted behavior with your answer, in this link https://regexr.com/4uqfu the matches there are not supposed to be valid but are still matching. Is it possible that you can help me resolve this?

Comment: Well, that is not your question. Those matches are due to the obligatory pattern part, `(?<!\w)(?<PhoneNumber>([2-9][0-9])([0-9]{2}){3}\b)` matches them. Why aren't `+45202122` and `+45202122` valid matches?

Comment: If you mean that the number that starts with a `Region` pattern (if it was matched) and has less than 8 digits after should not match? Please edit the question.

Comment: You're right, I've tried adding more details to my question, describing the requirements.

Comment: Those details do not clear out the issue. Your regex allows matching `45202122`. Do you mean you only want to match at whitespace boundaries? `(?<!\S)(?<Region>(?:\+|00)45)?(?<PhoneNumber>[2-9][0-9](?:[0-9]{2}){3})(?!\S)`? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%3f%3cRegion%3e%28%3f%3a%5c%2b%7c00%2945%29%3f%28%3f%3cPhoneNumber%3e%5b2-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29%7b3%7d%29%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=20212223+004520212223+%2b4520212223+24546577+12467223%0d%0a%2b45202122+%2b45202122%2b4520212223).

Comment: No the match can only be region+phonenumber with no letters, digits or special characters around it this means +12345678 matches as a no area code number, but has a special character in front of it so it should not be considered where as +4512345678 should match cause of area code +45 followed by 8 digits.

Comment: So, why is `453202122` not a valid number? `[2-9][0-9]` allows the `45` phone start.

Comment: Because its 9 digits and is not a Danish phone number. The first 0045 and +45 is region code followed by 8 digits.
I't like to admit that I made a mistake when testing your latest example and I went over it again and from what I can tell, it does seem to match the examples I throw at it as expected. As mentioned I am quite rookie at regex and for the most of the time its trial and error for me.